# Material 3 BottomNavigationView container has wrong color

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android

I have implemented a BottomNavigationView in my activity. Per documentation `app:backgroundTint` changes the container color, but when I use `app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"` it still gives me an awkward color.
How can I make it go completely white?

[image]

```xml
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/TextAppearance.FootballTicket.TitleSmall"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />
```

Comment: did you tried removing the elevation ?

Comment: @DrHowdyDoo By default it should have 3dp elevation but mine comes with 0 and when I change it nothing happens.

Comment: Can u show me your code ?

Comment: @DrHowdyDoo Edited question to contain code. The problem is `app:elevation` does nothing (no elevation present as of now). Also, if I change `app:backgroundTint` to any color, it does actually change but there's also an overlay, the exact one that makes the `BottomNavigationView` in the picture above to have this color instead of white!

Comment: Your code has elevation set to 6dp ?

Comment: @DrHowdyDoo Yes, as you can see in the code above `app:elevation="6dp"`, for testing purposes though, can't find why it still has no elevation. It should even override theme preferences.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247769/discussion-between-drhowdydoo-and-roozbeh-zarei).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem can be solved by adding the following attribute to the `BottomNavigationView`:

```xml
app:itemBackground="@android:color/white"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change color from theme file because material components depends on theme file

Comment: I did override theme file following Material 3 documentation and still, I can change anything except container background and elevation!